# How to change height of footer in accordion fashion

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to CSS and jquery.  I have a footer with a set height and a "Change Country" link along with text below it.  When I click the Change Country link, a div is dynamically added to the footer using AJAX.  The problem I am having is that the text I'm adding overflows the space below and I'm unable to scroll down to the other links. I have 2 questions... First, how do I change the height of the footer so that the user can scroll down to other links? Second, how do I do this so that the links below appear to be getting push down instead of just appearing?

Chris

Comment: Can you add a link to jsbin or codepen so that we can have a look?

Comment: Show us your source code in `fiddle.com` or something like  that.Edit your question with adequate requirements,else will get downvote.

Comment: Sounds like to have overflow hidden set somewhere on your footer